# Cancel fetch request in iOS SWIFT 2

Tags: ios, database, swift, core-data

I would like to use core data in my application. But I would like to implement a manager which can handle database, and I don't know how can I cancel the previous fetch request. I tried some techniques but they didn't work.

So these are my tasks:

- Fetch from core data
- If I start a new fetch cancel the previous fetch
- do these in a background thread

Summary: How can I cancel a core data fetch request?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion? Start out by watching the [Advanced NSOperations](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-226/) video from this year's WWDC. Also look at the resources and transcript links under the video. Lots of good information on multitasking.

Comment: Yeah thats the only one what I didnt try the operation queues, so you think i should try that?

I mean I will able to cancle the previous fetch request and start a new one?

Answer (score 0):

I interpret your question more as how to cancel pending core data requests, rather than anything specific to swift syntax.  Thus, the example is in ObjectiveC, but you can translate it easily enough.

Once a normal fetch request has been given to core data, there is no way to cancel it.  You have to wait for it to complete.

You can, however, cancel asynchronous fetch requests (i.e., those initiated with `NSAsynchronousFetchRequest`).

If you use `NSOperation` to queue your operations, you can cancel any pending operations, but you still can't cancel anything that is currently running.

However, there is no reason to port all of your code to `NSOperation` just for this because you can implement something similar this yourself in many ways.  Here is one option as a category on `NSManagedObjectContext`...

```
- (void)performCancelableBlock:(void(^)(void))block {
    [self performBlock:^{
        if (block) {
            NSUInteger count = [objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(cancelPendingBlocks)) unsignedIntegerValue];
            if (count == 0) {
                block();
            }
        }
    }];
}

- (void)cancelPendingBlocks {
    @synchronized(self) {
        NSUInteger count = [objc_getAssociatedObject(self, _cmd) unsignedIntegerValue];
        NSAssert(count+1 > 0, @"count has wrapped; queue is probably hung");
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, _cmd, @(count+1), OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
    }
    [self performBlock:^{
        @synchronized(self) {
            NSUInteger count = [objc_getAssociatedObject(self, _cmd) unsignedIntegerValue];
            NSAssert(count > 0, @"BUG - cancel count has become unbalanced");
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, _cmd, @(count-1), OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
        }
    }];
}
```

and a simple test to demonstrate what it does...

```
- (void)testCancelation {
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self makeMOC];

    // Expect that the original block ran to completion and didn't get "interrupted"
    XCTestExpectation *origExpectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"Original block"];
    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    [moc performBlock:^{
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        [origExpectation fulfill];
    }];
    NSUInteger __block normalBlockCount = 0, cancelBlockCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        [moc performBlock:^{
            ++normalBlockCount;
        }];
        [moc performCancelableBlock:^{
            ++cancelBlockCount;
        }];
    }
    [moc cancelPendingBlocks];

    // Expect that only blocks in the queue when the cancel request was issued are canceled
    XCTestExpectation *doneExpectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"Cancelable block after cancelation"];
    [moc performCancelableBlock:^{
        [doneExpectation fulfill];
    }];
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);

    [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:10 handler:nil];
    XCTAssertEqual(100, normalBlockCount);
    XCTAssertEqual(0, cancelBlockCount);
}
```